# Regarding Tfs Warehouse DB

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on agile & scrum methodology with tfs. While creating a task in tfs we use to assign it to a particular person,we use to give area,iteration,state etc... and while creating it we have an option called attachment in the tfs dashboard.That is used to attach relevant files according to our requirement. If we attach a file i need to know where we can find that attached file in Tfs_warehouse database & under which table?

Answer (score 0):

The attachments are not stored in the warehouse and you cannot report over the files attached to work items out-of-the-box.

If you want to use the attachments in your reports, you can use the TFS Client Object Model from C# code in your report to fetch the attachment based on the work item ID. You can use the [`WorkItemStore` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.aspx) to access this information.

If you want to do aggregate queries over attachments you'll have to build a custom warehouse adapter for TFS, which is very specific and difficult work to get right. I'd advise against it if not strictly required for your reporting needs.